# When inserting a PDF Object into my Worksheet using VBA it displays no icon and im not able to save my WorkBook afterwards

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert objects in a new table row. It works for images, word documents and outlook email messages. But when I try to insert a PDF the object displays no icon and I get errors when I try to save the workbook with this object embedded.

EDIT: Also not working for Word documents.

If I go and manually right-click the object > adobe acrobat document > convert and convert to .pdf it works.

I have searched and couldnt find anything similar, any help is welcome.

please find my code below:

```
Private Sub InsertButton_Click()
    If (noEmptyValues() = False) Then
        MsgBox "All fields are mandatory!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim FileObject As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CHANGES")

    Set table = Range("CHANGE_TABLE").ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Set newRow = table.ListRows.Add

    If (FileLocationTextBox.Value <> vbNullString) Then
       Set FileObject = ws.OLEObjects.Add(fileName:=FileLocationTextBox.Value, DisplayAsIcon:=True, Link:=False)
    End If

    With newRow
        .Range(2) = Now
        .Range(3) = ChangeTypeComboBox.Value
        .Range(4) = ExpenseTypeComboBox.Value
        .Range(6) = DescriptionTextBox.Value
        .Range(7) = FinancialImpactTextBox.Value
        FileObject.Top = .Range(9).Top
        FileObject.Left = .Range(9).Left
        FileObject.Height = .Range(9).Height + 20
        FileObject.Width = .Range(9).Width
        FileObject.Placement = xlMoveAndSize

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```